# onClick={OnButtomSubmit} function not working in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to use **onClick** for my button in React which is initially supposed to just print clicked in console, but is not working .

The Component where it is being called is :

```
import React from 'react'
import 'tachyons'

const ImageLinkForm=({OnInputChange,OnButtomSubmit}) =>{
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="center mt5 form br3 shadow-5 w-50">
                <input className="f3 pa2 w-70 center" type="Text" onChange={OnInputChange}></input>
                <button className="w-30 f4 grow link ph3 pv2 dib white bg-black pointer ma1" onClick={OnButtomSubmit}>Detect</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImageLinkForm
```

The component is used in App.js as follows :

```
<ImageLinkForm OnInputChange={this.OnInputChange} OnButtonSubmit={this.OnButtonSubmit} ></ImageLinkForm>
```

The definitions of the functions are:

```
OnInputChange=(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
OnButtonSubmit=()=>{
    console.log('clicked');
  }
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here .
PS: the onInputChange is working fine

Comment: there is a typo in `ImageLinkForm` component. `OnButtomSubmit`change that to `OnButtonSubmit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a typo:

```
OnButtomSubmit // change m to n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnButtonSubmit=()=>{
    console.log('clicked');
  }
```

there is a typo when you're bringing it in from props

```
const ImageLinkForm=({OnInputChange,OnButtomSubmit}) =>{ // you typed OnButtom with an m instead of an n
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a typo error in

```
<ImageLinkForm OnInputChange={this.OnInputChange} OnButtonSubmit={this.OnButtonSubmit} ></ImageLinkForm>
```

As you use `OnButtomSubmit` as prop in the component file and you are using `OnButtonSubmit` when using that prop.

Hope this will help